# How to serve static content over an Azure CDN with a dynamic resolver redirecting Urls from Ids?

Tags: azure, web-services, asp.net-core, media

**What we already have in place**

- Azure Blob Storage with static files, ir our case images
- Azure CDN in front of the Blob Storage
- ASP.NET Core Service

  - uploading images to the blob storage
  - saving meta data about the logical collection of images, called Asset

let's call this the media service

**How we use that**

- Let's say we have another service called the product service.
- Each product has a product picture associated with it.
- We create a new asset in the media service and get back an `AssetId`.
- The product service now stores this `AssetId` in his local database

**What we're looking for**

As long as we operate with the assets meta data in the back end life's good.

But at the end of the day we want to visualize the pictures in a WebUI. To do that we need to have the Url pointing back to the image on the blob storage / CDN.

Right now the back end actively resolves the Urls before the data flows to the WebUI. But there must be better way of doing this.

One feasible approach that comes to mind is to have a simple resolver middleware

`/images/{assetid}/{assetType}` -> Redirect to CDN Url

but then each call flows over this middleware instead of going to the CDN in first place before falling back to a resolver to get the correct Url.

What do I miss? What's the best practice any way to solve such basic thing in the micro-service area?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would not use a middleware component to redirect the URLs, because as you mentioned, the client will always contact first your middleware component, and there is an additional unnecessary call and overhead. The nature of the CDN is to serve the assets in a global distributed network, so your assets will be indexed to the CDN edges and it will be served from the closest edge to the client. You should be able to use the WebUI component and use the CDN Urls (https://.azureedge.net/*). In case you need to use redirect rules, you can use the CDN features to perform redirect rules. Note: Depending on the CDN service you are using, you may need to upgrade CDN pricing tier to Premium. Eg. Verizon you need to use Premium tier to have ability for redirect rules.